# How to clip image/view with mask from CGRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cgrect

I have a class in which I draw a shape using:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{...}
```

I would like to use this shape to mask my image or view, which is actually filled progress bar. How can I do that?

For now I have only this class and progressFilled.png... nothing more. Let me know how to clip this image with shape built by class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"progressFilled.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: @steam Hm, but I have this drawInRect in separated class and it draws me the mask.